# i cannot understand what does theese error mean

Tags: c++, class

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    class Student {
        int age;
        char first_name[30];
        char second_name[30];
        int standard;
        public:
        void set_age(int a) {
            age=a;
        }
        void set_standard(int b){
            standard=b;
        }
        void set_last_name(char temp[]) {
            strcpy(second_name,temp);
        }
        void get_age() {
            cout<<age;
        }
        void get_last_name(){
            cout<<second_name;
        }
        void get_first_name() {
            cout<<first_name;
        }
        void get_standard(){
            cout<<standard;
        }
    };

    void Student::set_first_name(char temp[]){
        strcpy(first_name,temp);
    }

    int main() {
        int age, standard;
        string first_name, last_name;

        cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

        Student st;
        st.set_age(age);
        st.set_standard(standard);
        st.set_first_name(first_name);
        st.set_last_name(last_name);

        cout << st.get_age() << "\n";
        cout << st.get_last_name() << ", " << st.get_first_name() << "\n";
        cout << st.get_standard() << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << st.to_string();

        return 0;
    }
```

errors

```
Solution.cpp:35:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void Student::set_first_name(char*)’
 void Student::set_first_name(char temp[]){
      ^~~~~~~
Solution.cpp:35:6: note: no functions named ‘void Student::set_first_name(char*)’
Solution.cpp:6:7: note: ‘class Student’ defined here
 class Student {
       ^~~~~~~
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Solution.cpp:48:8: error: ‘class Student’ has no member named ‘set_first_name’; did you mean ‘get_first_name’?
     st.set_first_name(first_name);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        get_first_name
Solution.cpp:49:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘Student::set_last_name(std::__cxx11::string&)’
     st.set_last_name(last_name);
                               ^
Solution.cpp:18:10: note: candidate: ‘void Student::set_last_name(char*)’
     void set_last_name(char temp[]) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You have provided a definition of the method, but the method is not declared in the class.

Add this line *inside* the Student class to provide a declaration:

```
void set_first_name(char temp[]);
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't declare your function in your class

add this line to class body and the error will disappear

```
void set_first_name(char temp[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues:

`cout` cannot print `void`.

you haven't declared a function but you try to define it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Student {
    int age;
    char first_name[30];
    char second_name[30];
    int standard;
    public:
    void set_age(int a) {
        age=a;
    }
    void set_standard(int b){
        standard=b;
    }
    void set_last_name(const char* temp) {
        strcpy(second_name,temp);
    }
    void get_age() {
        cout<<age;
    }
    void get_last_name(){
        cout<<second_name;
    }
    void get_first_name() {
        cout<<first_name;
    }
    void get_standard(){
        cout<<standard;
    }
    void set_first_name(const char* temp){
    strcpy(first_name,temp);
}
};



int main() {
    int age, standard;
    string first_name, last_name;

    cin >> age >> first_name >> last_name >> standard;

    Student st;
    st.set_age(age);
    st.set_standard(standard);
    st.set_first_name(first_name.c_str());
    st.set_last_name(last_name.c_str());

    st.get_age();
    st.get_last_name();
    st.get_first_name();
    st.get_standard();
    cout << "\n";
    //cout << st.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like `void set_first_name(char temp[])` in the deceleration of your student class. Also, strings are not the same as char arrays and must be casted to that type. I recommend using strings in your class and not char arrays. This would be causing your last few errors.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Oblivion's answer that you cannot cout first_name, second_name as well. First_name and second_name are pointers to the first element of the character array. Printing them would lead to just printing their addresses in the console.
You have to change these function declarations:

```
void get_last_name(){
    cout<<second_name; 
} 
void get_first_name(){
    cout<<first_name;
}
```

You need to add '\0' (end of string character) to the character arrays and then print it as a string. Check out how to do it by searching. You will learn a lot about working of character arrays and string.